# copy active row and insert below even with active filter

Tags: excel, vba, filter, insert, autofilter

Have succeeded to make code to insert 1,3 or 5 rows of copies of the active row - below the active row.
However it does not work when the filter is on.

I have a sheet with
Week, Employee number, data - sorted by employee number.
Filtered on one employee.

Now, I would like to copy the row I am marking and insert x number of rows below - and "stay on the activerow" - even though I have to do whatever gymnastics to remove and add filter... I hope and trust there is another way.

I have found the "SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)" but cannot seem to place it coorectly - it inserted 5 rows in the top of my sheet :-)

I hope someone can help... My code looks like this

```
Sub Insert5Rows()

Dim xcount As Integer
xcount = 5

    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(xcount, 0)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
     
End Sub
```

Thanks a bunch in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Insert Copied Rows When Active **AutoFilter**

- I don't think it is possible (surely not reliable) without removing the filter.
- The procedures `getFilterData` and `restoreFilters` will remove and reapply respectively the filters.
- It surely is not tested enough, so take caution. Any feedback is most welcome.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub insertData()
    
    Const CopiesCount As Long = 5
    
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Selection.Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range: Set cel = Selection.Cells(1)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = cel.CurrentRegion
    
    Dim FilterData As Variant
    Dim avoidFilter As Boolean
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        FilterData = getFilterData(rg)
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        avoidFilter = True
    End If
    
    With rg.Rows(cel.Row - rg.Row + 1)
        .Copy
        With .Offset(1).Resize(CopiesCount)
            .Insert xlShiftDown
        End With
    End With
    
    If avoidFilter Then
        restoreFilters rg, FilterData
    Else
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

End Sub

Function getFilterData( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    With rg.Worksheet.AutoFilter
        With .Filters
            Dim FilterData As Variant: ReDim FilterData(1 To .Count, 1 To 3)
            Dim n As Long
            For n = 1 To .Count
                With .Item(n)
                    If .On Then
                        FilterData(n, 1) = .Criteria1
                        If .Operator Then
                            FilterData(n, 2) = .Operator
                            On Error Resume Next ' Not investigated errors.
                            FilterData(n, 3) = .Criteria2
                            On Error GoTo 0
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
            Next n
        End With
    End With
    getFilterData = FilterData
End Function

Sub restoreFilters( _
        ByRef rg As Range, _
        ByVal BackupData As Variant)
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To UBound(BackupData, 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(BackupData(n, 1)) Then
            If BackupData(n, 2) Then
                rg.AutoFilter Field:=n, Criteria1:=BackupData(n, 1), _
                    Operator:=BackupData(n, 2), Criteria2:=BackupData(n, 3)
            Else
                rg.AutoFilter Field:=n, Criteria1:=BackupData(n, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: Wauw, Amazing how much code you need for an actually simple task. BUT IT WORKED!!! However, I am actually having my filter in row 3, as I have buttons in the top of the sheet. Where on earth do I need to change something to set the filter on row 3...?? Thanks a bunch for the reply... Really appreciated.

Comment: Can you share where exactly the data is located, e.g. `A3:G100`? `Set rg = cel.CurrentRegion` should have taken care of it. But your data is probably not contiguous,  i.e. you may have some values in row 2 which should be empty. This complicates matters, but surely can be fixed. You could just ask another question describing what is wrong with the code also adding some sample data and screenshots.

Comment: I am not yet allowed to add sreenshots :-) But yes, I have buttons in row 1and 2 and data from row 3 - and onwards, the number of rows increasing every week and as we use this code (that add rows)...  but always from a3...

Comment: aaarh, I read about CurrentRegion and just added an empty row above the row I want the filter in ... Now it works...

Comment: Damn it (sorry). It does not work, when there was no filtering done prior to clicking. Then it does not restore the filters.