# VBA Excel unFiltering and re-filtering

Tags: excel, vba

In my question [copy active row and insert below even with active filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66275031/copy-active-row-and-insert-below-even-with-active-filter)
I have received a marvellous piece of code, but I accidently "approved" the answer before testing completely. Now, it turns out that if the filter was not applied (no filtering was done) prior to code execution, then the filter is not reapplied.

Hope someone can assist in finding the little tweak that does the trick.
Guess that the filterdata should be allowed to be empty, but I am simply not able to figure out how or where to make this adjustment...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really hope someone can help in cracking this little nut for me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had to fix it some how, so I made an if.
So - If there is no filter used, just insert a row, else remove filters, add the row and insert the filters again.

```
Dim I As Long
Dim Cnt As Integer

Cnt = 0
    
    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter
        For I = 1 To .Filters.Count
            If .Filters(I).On Then
               Cnt = Cnt + 1
            End If
        Next I
    End With
    
 If Cnt = 0 Then 
    'insert a row copy
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(CopiesCount, 0)).EntireRow.Insert 
    Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Else -- the code from the other question
```

Perhaps not the most pretty thing, but it works.